# External frequency as input to an FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, nexys

I want to take frequency generated by a function generator as input to an FPGA board (Nexys 3). I am trying to use a square pulse of 10 kHz as input to the FPGA. So to test how to take an input from an external source I wrote the following basic code:

```
module freq(
    input ip,
    output op
    );
assign op = ip;

endmodule
```

After assigning the input and output ports on the FPGA, I tried giving a 10 kHz frequency as input to the board. When I tried to view the output on a digital oscilloscope, I couldn't view any output waveform. I asked my professor regarding this but she couldn't understand why this was happening.

[image]

This is the pin-out diagram of Nexys 3 board. Initially K2 was given as the input and K1 was given as the output. When we couldn't get any waveform we changed the input and output ports but the result was the same.

The function generator, the digital oscilloscope, and all the wires used for this were tested and it was found that they were working properly.

Is there a reason why I can't take a frequency as input from an external source?

PS:- I intend to use this frequency taken from an external source as clock instead of the internal clock since the task given to us states that we have to use an external frequency.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to work? I mean, you don't even tell what kind of signal you generated with the waveform generator, so how do you know it was compatible with the FPGA input?

Comment: @Justme I am trying to give a square pulse of 10khz as input to the FPGA

Comment: Yes, you told that already. It contains no new information to determine what kind of signal you had and if it had compatible voltages with FPGA input, or did it damage due to overvoltage, etc.

Comment: Can you please specify by what exactly do you mean by what kind of signal ? And the chances of it getting damaged due to overvoltage is low since the voltage of the frequency was 1V peak to peak.

Comment: For example the amplitude and offset. Basically all the settings I would need to replicate your experiment. Now, 1Vpp signal, was it terminated or not on the FPGA board, and did you use the terminated or unterminated setting on the generator? If you had it on wrong setting, the amplitude might have been 0.5Vpp or 2Vpp. And if you did not add offset, any voltage below 0V is illegal and can damage the FPGA pin. Also 1V positive peak is not likely regarded as logic high. But depends on FPGA IO pin voltage levels. What levels it uses?

Comment: What did the input waveform look like on the oscilloscope? Show a picture.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't have a picture right now with me since I am not in college but it was your normal square pulse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital chips generally don't work with 1Vpp signals.

You must determine what are the logic voltage levels the FPGA input works with, and since you have an oscilloscope at your disposal, make sure with the oscilloscope that the generator analog output signal is as per FPGA digital logic input expectations before connecting it to avoid damage, and also after it is connected to see if it still matches.

A typical example might be 3.3V digital logic. Logic 0 or low is 0V, not going below -0.3V to avoid damage, and logic 1 or high is 3.3V, not exceeding 3.6V to avoid damage.

Comment: I will test this out tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @BojackHorseman, JustMe is spot on here. I'd add to set the signal generator to 3 V, to avoid any unintended overshoot, and pass it through a 2K2 series resistor. The resistor reduces the current into the FPGA pin clamp diodes if there's any mishap, saving your FPGA.

Comment: Check the FPGA datasheet for what voltage range is allowed on the attempted port/pin.  Could be 5V, 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.8V, etc.

Comment: @Justme i tried it today 
3.3V was the required input voltage